# Passportjs not calling isAuthenticate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm running into an issue with my index.js file trying to call isAuthenticate() using passportjs with expressjs. When I make the function call req.isAuthenticated() never gets called and will always return false.
Brief explanation, I'm trying to authenticate the user so they can access pages that they are authorized to view.

Here is a link to the repo  https://github.com/SpotOnSoftwareInc/web-app

note: this was code that I inherited from someone else and a lot of these tools are new to me.

```
'module.exports = function (passport) {
 router.get('/login', login.get);
 router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local-login',{
    //session: false,
    successRedirect : '/registerprocess',
    failureRedirect : '/register',
    failureFlash: true
 }));

function isLoggedInBusAdmin(req, res, next) {
    //if user is authenticated in the session, carry on

    if (req.isAuthenticated() && ((req.user[0].role === 'busAdmin') || (req.user[0].role === 'saasAdmin'))){
        return next();
    }
    req.flash("permission", "You do not have permission to access that page");
    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('back');
}'
```

lib\auth.js

```
`function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log('ENTERED IS AUTHENTICATED');
    isValidToken(req.db, req.headers.authorization, function (result) {
        if (!result) {
            console.log('Not Authenticated');
            return res.send(403);
        } else {
            req.mobileToken = result[0];
            console.log('Authenticated PASS');
            return next();
        }

    });
}
}`
```

Comment: do you call `passport.initialise()` when the server loads?

Comment: yea I call it in my app.js file @SimonH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error in my app.js file

instead of calling 
employee.find({_id: id}, function (err, user){

i was calling
employee.findById({_id: id}, function (err, user){